# Table right hand vertical border line has a gap

Tags: tables

Im totally new to Latex and not a developer. 
My table seems to leave a gap near the top right hand vertical line. what is wrong here?

```
\begin{tabular}{ | p{3.40cm} | *{5}{p{1.8cm}|} }  
\hline \\
& \b{Title} & \b{Title} &\b{Title} &\b{Title} &\b{Title}  \\
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\b{subhead}} \\
\hline
\b{text} & \b{text} & \b{text} & \b{text} & \b{text} & \b{text}  \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please provide complete but small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. in it you have defined `b` which is unknown to use

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. \b seems to bold the text. Not sure why it works for me.
Any idea why i get that gap on the top right of the border ?

Comment: cause of your problem is `\hline \\ ` before the first row of table. remove `\\ ` after it. anyway, provide complete small document with your table. maybe someone can advise you how to make better looking table ...

Comment: By default, `\b` inserts an under-bar in text mode. If it renders its argument in **bold**, it must because something or somebody has modified the `\b` macro.

Comment: Thank you. that works
How about coloured banded rows ?

Comment: \documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{3.40cm} | p{1.8cm} | p{1.8cm} | p{1.8cm} | p{1.8cm} | p{1.8cm} |}  \hline 
\ & {Title} & {Title} & {Title} & {Title} & {Title}  \\
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{subhead} \\
\hline
{text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text}  \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

Comment: How can i add banded row colours to this:

Comment: How can i add banded row colours to this: @Zarko

Comment: Cant figure out how to add the code as a document to here

Comment: please, edit your question and add code there. and don't use document class `minimal`. it not provide all functionality for your table. use `article`. sorry, but i'm lost in your comments ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- please read some introductory text about writing table. for example: [LaTeX/Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)
- also look to [Wie Tabellen eigentlich aussehen sollten](https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/), a very interesting/educative presentation how to design nice looking table
- for minimal working example, a small but complete document, never use document class `minimal`. it not assure all latex capability. rather use `article`
- for coloring rows, columns aor particular cells use package `xcolor` with option `table`:

  `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`

  and for coloring some row add before this row

  `\rowcolor{<color name>}`

  for details see documentation for `xcolor` and for `colortbl` (which `xcolor` used for coloring tables)
- i would write your table as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ p{3.40cm} *{5}{p{1.8cm}} }
    \toprule
    & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Title} 
    & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Title}           \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{subhead}                     \\
    \midrule
text    & text  & text  & text  & text  & text  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- however, if you persist with your approach and colored row, than try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ | p{3.40cm} | *{5}{p{1.8cm} |} }
    \hline
    & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Title} 
    & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Title}           \\
    \hline \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!30}
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{subhead}                           \\
    \hline
{text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text}     \\
    \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]